# Setting up Stripe Cloud Module in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code, stripe.net

apologies beforehand for my naïveté.  I started learning Obj. C about six weeks ago so I'm very new to iOS development, a lot of things are not very obvious to me still.

I am building my second app using Parse.  This time it is an e-com app so would like to use Apple Pay with Stripe as the payment provider.  Would like to use Parse as the server for Stripe.

I have already linked (I think?) Cloud Code to my Parse account's app (I guess it's all in JavaScript?  so that was pretty confusing for me).

But I'm not even sure where to start with the initial Parse/Stripe documentation (https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#stripe).  Where am I supposed to put the following code:

```
var Stripe = require('stripe');
Stripe.initialize('mySecretKey');
```

Comment: Not a naïve question at all. The instructions are on the github page for Parse's sample Stripe app: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseStore .  It seems as if those two lines go into the main.js javascript file and then you add that .js file to your Xcode project somehow using the cd, add, and deploy commands in your terminal.

Comment: You should follow [cloud code guide](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide) first. It shows you how to setup the cloud code and test the cloud function.

Comment: Thanks for both answers.  I decided to just test the Stripe/Parse functionality just through the Example app first before implementing into my own app.  

I followed the instructions and put my application keys, etc. in.  But it does not seem to link to my Stripe dashboard?  Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

As Lyndsey Scott noted, I could see in Parse's example app that the code goes into main.js.